# Azure Message Queue -Generate Shared Access Signature

Tags: azure, authorization, azure-queues

I'm having trouble trying to send a POST message to an Azure SB Queue using PostMan.

The error I get is 401 40103: Invalid authorization token signature
My issue is generating the SAS as I'm trying to follow various articles and examples but I must be missing/overlooking/not understanding something.

If I describe what I've done, hopefully it'll become obvious where I'm making a mistake.

My Queue URL is https://GTRAzure.servicebus.windows.net/subscriptionpreference
My Policy is `Submit`
I've chosen an expiry date for December: `1512086400`

My string-to-sign is https://gtrazure.servicebus.windows.net/subscriptionpreference\n1512086400 which is then encoded as `https%3A%2F%2Fgtrazure.servicebus.windows.net%2Fsubscriptionpreference%5Cn1512086400`

I then sign this using the Primary Key I get from the Submit policy. I'm using this to test: https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html

This generates a code like `425d5ff8beb8da58e6f97e45462037e25ea56bcb63470f9b28761fa012f61090` using SHA-256 Which I then base-64 encode to get `NDI1ZDVmZjhiZWI4ZGE1OGU2Zjk3ZTQ1NDYyMDM3ZTI1ZWE1NmJjYjYzNDcwZjliMjg3NjFmYTAxMmY2MTA5MA==`

I then put it all together to get this which I place in the text of the Authorization header
`SharedAccessSignature sig=NDI1ZDVmZjhiZWI4ZGE1OGU2Zjk3ZTQ1NDYyMDM3ZTI1ZWE1NmJjYjYzNDcwZjliMjg3NjFmYTAxMmY2MTA5MA==&se=1512086400&skn=Submit=&sr=https%3A%2F%2Fgtrazure.servicebus.windows.net%2Fsubscriptionpreference%5Cn1512086400`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the string to sign which you are providing is incorrect because `\n` is not getting treated as new line which generates encoded value as :

> https%3A%2F%2Fgtrazure.servicebus.windows.net%2Fsubscriptionpreference%5Cn1512086400

which gives Authorization failure.

But if it is treated as new line, it will give value like this:

> https%3A%2F%2Fgtrazure.servicebus.windows.net%2Fsubscriptionpreference%0A1512086400

which will not give error.